# T-SQL How to unescape or decode string?

Tags: string, t-sql, decode, sql-server-2012, encode

I have a string that is record in the database in encode format (encoded with Javascript) and I need to decode it. The "tabs" and the "new line" characters are escaped with symbols like '%09' or '%09%09%09%09%0D%0A' and others and it's hard do say what symbols with what should be replaced.

Is there a tricky way to do this or I should found which encode combination I have in the string and replace them?